# Is is safe to dig under the patio to install a drain tile?

Tags: basement, waterproofing, mold

We have a mold/water issue in our basement wall that is concrete block foundation. No visible cracks, but based on what I've researched, sounds like it might be coming through the blocks. On the outside, this section is below a concrete patio.

Is is safe to dig under the patio to install a drain tile? Any other ideas to fix this? I just caulked the expansion gap but have read that it's not a permanent fix. Seems like grading is the best fix for this, but I'm struggling to figure out what to do with the patio in the way. Thanks in advance!

[Pics](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o45YyCXc_gmngGfiGv-slwGGnecq8MNK?usp=share_link)

Comment: There's a downspout from your gutters right there. First thing I would do is improvise some way to channel that water away better.

Comment: I considered that as well, but the downspout drains on the side of the house as opposed to the back, where the water damage is present.

Comment: Please put your images in the post using the editor. I can't seem them on my network.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea for you to dig under a concrete patio unless you're really good at compacting the ground back in to prevent the patio from sinking. You could possibly have a company bore under it but that gets expensive. Check for gaps between the patio and the exterior wall and seal them.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for confirming my worries about going under the patio. I figured there was a "commercial solution", but like many on this forum, definitely looking for a DIY solution. There was a small cap between the wall & the patio, and I recently sealed it up. But, I know the caulk will probably fail over time and need upkeep, so I'm trying to brainstorm ideas to help it out. Do you think a drain tile in the area in blue would help?https://drive.google.com/file/d/19mFnRSulQIqBfct0amxQryBXNBclQs2g/view?usp=sharing

There is a decent downward slope in the grass area it would go into.